# Must have all 3 checked boxes checked to enable button

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need some assistance with the following script. I'm using this as a pop up when someone is trying to add a product to the cart.

Currently the button will become active if one of the check boxes is selected (not sure why it isn't working on fiddle) but what I want is to have it disabled until ALL 3 checkboxes are checked.

I need to mention, total there are 2 different pop ups for 2 different brands. For 1 brand there is only 1 checkbox that needs to be checked for the button to become active but for this 2nd pop up there are 3 checkboxes. So in saying that i need this to work with 1 checkboxes selected as well as needing to have all 3 checkboxes checked.

```
<div>
  <div class="vet-diet-info">

    <p>
      <label>
        <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox"> Agree.
      </label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>
        <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox"> Agree.
      </label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>
        <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox"> Agree.
      </label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <a id="mainbutton" href="javascript:void(0)" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-info" disabled="disabled">Confirm Purchase</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>


function SetVetDietsEventsPopup() {
  jq("#checkbox").off("change").on("change", function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      jq("#mainbutton").removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
      jq("#mainbutton").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
  });
  jq("#btnVetDietsConfirmPurchase").off("click").on("click", function() {
    if (jq(this).is(":disabled")) {
      return false;
    } else {
      RunAddToCartButtonClickEvent();
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5xy0qtvy/1/

Answer (score 2):

First of all id is **unique** you **can't** use the same id for more than one element instead use class

```
var numItems = $('.checkbox').length; //number of checkboxes
var checked = 0;

$('.checkbox').each(function() {
if ( $(this).prop('checked') ) { 
checked++;
}
});

if (numItems === checked) 
$("#mainbutton").removeAttr('disabled');
 else
alert('please check all the checkboxes');
```

don't forget to change all the `id="checkbox"` to `class="checkbox"`

Comment: Consider using [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of attriibutes.

Answer (score 0):

**Update** Fixed where I had the logic inverted.

As alread mentioned Id must be unique.

This can be done withouth the each loop however. Use `:not` in conjunction with `:checked` to see if there are any unchecked boxes.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".vet-diet-info [name='checkbox']").click(function() {;
    $("#mainbutton").prop("disabled", $(".vet-diet-info [name='checkbox']:not(:checked)").length !== 0);
    console.log($("#mainbutton").prop("disabled"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="vet-diet-info">

    <p>
      <label>
        <input name="checkbox" type="checkbox">Agree.
      </label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>
        <input name="checkbox" type="checkbox">Agree.
      </label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>
        <input name="checkbox" type="checkbox">Agree.
      </label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <a id="mainbutton" href="javascript:void(0)" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-info" disabled="disabled">Confirm Purchase</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```